# Are non-cached js-scripts attached to the main file on ajax-get request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm using the following script to request new content to a file called index.html:

```
function addJS(js_urls) {
  $.each(js_urls, function(index, value) {
      $.ajax({
          type: 'GET',
          async: 'false', //We should not cache dynamic js-scripts
          dataType: 'script',
          url: value
      })
  })
}

function updatePage(data) {
  if(data['js']) {addJS(data['js']);}  //If any js-scripts are requested, load them
  $.each(data, function(index, value) {
      $('#' + index).html(value);
  });
  return false; //Stop link from redirecting
}

function ajaxRequest(url) {
  if(ajaxReq) {ajaxReq.abort();} //Abort current ajax requests if they exist
  ajaxReq = $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      cache: 'false', //We should not cache content
      url: url,
      dataType: 'json',
      success: updatePage
  });
}
```

And lets say that my index.html looks like this:

```
<div id="content">Content to be replace</div>
```

To clarify what happens here. The ajax request return json data, if that json data contains an entry called "js", then the urls in that entry are loaded through the addJS function. As you can see, I'm not caching the js-scripts.

So my question is, if i request a new url, using the ajaxRequest function, will the js-scripts i've already loaded disappear? Or will they be there so that I can use them through the new content?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, the answer is "no", your already-loaded scripts will not "disappear."  However, if you're reloading scripts that define global functions or global variables, then things you've changed will be overwritten.

In other words, if you've got a script that does something like this:

```
var globalvar = "hello world";
```

and in the course of processing stuff your page somewhere does:

```
  if (whatever) globalvar = "goodbye world";
```

then if you reload the script, that variable will be set back to its original value.

Comment: Okay, that answered my question :). Bonus question: What if i do want the js-script to dissapear when loading new content?

Comment: What do you mean by, "disappear"?  Can you describe the effect that you do (or don't) want?

Comment: My problem is that users on my site navigate using an ajax framework. So after 4-5 different page views, the js-scripts "pile up". I wan't to clean out any page-specific js-scripts before showing new content to the user.

Comment: Well there's not any built-in way to clean out the Javascript namespace. As long as your page is alive, it's there. Now, what you can do is to arrange for your scripts to work like jQuery does: keep everything inside of a very small number of global names. Then when you reload a script, you're basically resetting everything back to the original state.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the quick replies. One last question, will the js-script "pile up" make my website sluggish? They primarily consist of functions and a bit of code that runs directly.

Comment: Well things probably don't get *better* over time, due to garbage collection etc. But I used to work on a big (huge, really) web application that kept an outer window around for the life of a session. It had **lots** of Javascript, and I don't recall any significant problems at all that could be traced to the page getting "old."